# MySql query request time and server load

Tags: mysql, request

I have in my homepage 10 requests from the same table, each request has different condition so that's why I made 10 requests. This table has 12 columns. My question is .. Does it make a different for

**Page Load time and Server Load**  If I just need to request 6 columns from this table and I make the request as **(SELECT * FROM...)** instead of making the request like **(SELECT columns,columns,columns,columns,columns,columnsFROM....)** ?

Any information or suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. You specify columns, not rows, between SELECT and FROM. Rows is what the query returns. But, generally speaking, select * is always evil, because changes to the database change the behaviour of your program. Specify the *columns* you're interested in instead. Also, if you're interested in only some columns, it's less work for the database if you specify them.

Comment: well it sounds fair, But what about page loading time? would it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting only the columns you really need will always be faster than a select *, except in the case when you select all the columns. Even then, specifying the columns is preferrable, because changes to the database won't change what your code is doing.

The larger your columns are, the more difference you'll see. Imagine a table like this:

```
create table person (
    id integer,
    name varchar(20),
    photo blob
);
```

Now you select `select * from person where id>=10 and id<=20`. This means the mysql server has to read all matching records from the database, including the photo blob which can be large, and pass all of it to your application, just to have your application throw away the photo which makes 99% of the selected data. If you're throwing away the photo anyway, `select id, name from person ...` will be much faster AND put less load on the machine, which is important on a heavily loaded website with lots of visitors at the same time.

Of course, if your table has 6 integer columns, and your decision is select * for all of them, or select 4 specific ones, the effect is less noticable.

If you have a table like the above, and you have selects that include id and name only, but no photo, it makes sense to put a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on these two columns. That way, when selecting, the database server needs to read just the key, and won't even have to load the photo from disk.